# How do I check all the gems with its versions in my Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, gemfile

When I go with `gem list` from my app folder, the terminal displays the list of all gems installed on my local machine. I want instead to see the project related gems.

Comment: http://bundler.io/v1.10/commands.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

`bundle list` to show project related gems

To see some gems version, you can chain comands and use `grep`

exp.

`bundle list | grep rails` will list all gems  that containt word `rails`, such as `rails`, `jquery-rails`, ...

Answer (score 1):

`bundle show` is what you are looking for